# SF book cover with a gorilla-like being in a space suit coming through an archway

Tags: story-identification, teleportation

The cover art is mostly what I remember.

There was a being in a space suit coming through an archway (similar to a metal detector); the being resembled a gorilla.

It was carrying its helmet under one arm. The plot as I recall had to do with a Transporter, each time the transporter was used the user would come out the other end in a somewhat different version of their world. The longer the distance traveled the more distorted the version of their world was at the other end.

Comment: @DVK I'm not sure that [tag:time-travel] belongs. It may be some form of quantum travel between parallel universes. At least, that was my first thought.

Comment: We're likely going to need more detail. Variations on this theme are not uncommon. If you can recall of couple of memorable scenes from the book you might be pleasantly surprised.

Comment: @Xantec - I'm not sure if you're right, but just for the record, I simply added the story-ID tag (for entirely ulterior motives - I have that tag on ignore), the time-travel tag was there from the original OP's post :)

Comment: @DVK Oh, my mistake then, sorry. I had assumed it was already Story-ID'd and that you added the other.

Comment: @Xantec - NP, the diff screen can be a wee bit confusing :)

Comment: @DVK I'll admit that I didn't even look at it :-O

Answer (score 9):

I'm pretty sure this is [*The Infinitive of Go*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Infinitive_of_Go) by John Brunner.

[image: cover scan]

The archway is in fact a teleporter booth (or rather what is initially believed to be a teleporter). The being (a human from an alternate universe that's distant enough to have a slightly different physical appearance) isn't carrying a helmet but a briefcase in the picture, but I think he would have been carrying a helmet in the plot (as is common, the cover picture conflates several scenes).

Comment: Thank you, this is indeed the book I was looking for. The cover art is slightly different but they tend to change with each re-print. Thanks again, I will see if Uncle Hugos bookstore has a copy.

Comment: @R.C.Bergstrom When cover art changes, it's usually a different artist drawing a different picture. Do you know which edition this was? There's no cover art slightly different from this one on [ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1718).